# What happen the data is bigger than malloc declares?

Tags: c, malloc

I am new to C and I have a question about `malloc`. Here is the code:

```
  int *array = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
  if (array != NULL) {
     printf("success \n");
  }

  array[0] = 1;
  array[1] = 1;
  array[2] = 1;
  array[3] = 2; // I assume this should fail ?
  array[4] = 1; // I assume this should fail ?

  printf(" %d \n", array[3]);
```

Does it mean the `malloc` is only a memory allocation hint but not upper limit ? If yes, how do I enforce the upper limit in C ?

Comment: Undefined behavior: Anything can happen.

Comment: C language doesn't enforce any bound checking. It's all up to you to assure that no memory violations happens.

Comment: `// I assume this should fail ?` is the correct comment. It *might not* fail, but always assume that it will.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't mandate any bounds checking - the behavior on writing past the end of the array is *undefined*.  Depending on what you overwrite, your code may crash immediately, or it may corrupt other data, or it may work as expected.

Neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to issue any warning or throw any exception on writing past the end of the array.  You are expected to simply Not Do That.

Answer (score 0):

In this context of memory manipulation, it is important for you to understand what it is you're actually doing when you are declaring this dynamic memory allocation.

Your "array" pointer is located on the stack and points to the first item (the first 4 bytes) of a continuous block of memory (12 bytes (3xsizeof(int)) which is located ON THE HEAP.

When you try to access this heap space memory, through the [N] operator, you're asking the compiler to perform some pointer arithmetic to allow you to access the data contained in memory at the location (array + (N)*sizeof(int)) ON THE HEAP.

So when you try to access array[3], you are attempting to access a 4 byte memory location that is located directly after the last memory space you allocated for your array, this could be many things, including your own data from a previous allocation!

As the other responses to this post have stated, this is undefined behaviour, and should be avoided, as you cannot control what data you manipulate when you access "out of bounds" data.

Comment: Note: _heap_ and _stack_ are a common model of memory - but one not required by C.